# Raspberry Pi 4, terrible performance at the USB3 port

Tags: usb, data-transfer, ntfs

I have installed my Raspi 4 freshly today (latest Raspberry Pi Os). The SD Card performance is kind of okay (~40 MB/s write). However the USB3 performance is terrible. I have plugged in a mobile mechanical harddrive (with blue USB3 ports, including a suitable cable) that shows ~75 MB/s continuous write rate on the USB3 ports of my PC. On the Raspi 4 it only achieves ~20 MB/s, which is even less than the SD card! Same with a USB3 flash drive (~50 MB/s on the PC, ~20 MB/s on the RPi 4).

This irritates me because I have read about benchmarks where people have claimed to achieve >300 MB/s (I presume that they have not confused bits and bytes) with the RPi 4. Of course, my mobile drive can't perform that high, but given this nominal performance margin of the board, I'd expected the drive to perform near its maximum (~75 MB/s).

CPU frequency rises to 1.5GHz under load, as it should be.

Is there anything to do to enable the USB3 functionality? Anything else to check what the bottleneck could be?

I have checked performance by executing the following command:

```
time seq 1 100000000 > test.txt
```

and dividing the final file size (888888898 Bytes) by the displayed real time.

Reference to the performance claims:

https://magpi.raspberrypi.org/articles/raspberry-pi-4-specs-benchmarks

Comment: do you take into consideration the time taken by `seq` itself? because `time seq 1 100000000 > /dev/null` takes 5-6 seconds without any disk writes - also, that benchmark is probably misleading - probably using large block sizes to achieve that rate ... try something like `time dd if=/dev/zero bs=10M count=100 of=test.txt` then change it to `time dd if=/dev/zero bs=1M count=1000 of=test.txt` and `time dd if=/dev/zero bs=100M count=10 of=test.txt` to see how block size can effect benchmark results

Comment: No, I didn't take the performance of seq into account. I just assumed that generating number strings isn't all that costly. Anyways, I solved the problem, it was NTFS' fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After unsuccessfully trying the quirks mode (see Bra1n's answer), I read somewhere else that NTFS (which was the file system that has already been on the harddrive) is a performance impact on the Pi.

And, bingo, formatting the drive to ext4 got me the expected ~70-75 MB/s (remember, in the "old days" of mechanical drives the data rate changed with radial head position).

Since I have never formatted an external drive from Linux, I also had to learn, that you need to format it under the regular user account in order to gain write access to the drive.

However, it's a little disappointing that NTFS performs so bad. I am not so sure if this is really NTFS' fault, or if it's just the programmers being reluctant to optimize a driver originating from "Windoze".

Comment: Ah you never mentioned it was formatted with NTFS, I believe translating to and from NTFS is very processor intensive on the PI

Comment: The CPU load should've been the giveaway!! Any filesystem written by microsoft sits at the bottom of the ladder when it comes to performance

Comment: @Bra1n: the simple reason is, I did not know that it was relevant. Sorry.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Comment: Done. Sorry, I forgot to do it because SE prevented me from doing so immediately after I posted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert on this but I've read the Pi4 is very fussy about USB adaptors, additionally some people have seen improvements by enableing 'quirks mode' for the adaptor although in my experience performance was better without on the adaptors I used. Some good information on all the above here https://jamesachambers.com/raspberry-pi-4-usb-boot-config-guide-for-ssd-flash-drives/